# Table for feature layer in PostGIS database cannot be published and enabled on GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql

I have tried to publish a table for feature layer in a PostGIS database to GeoServer 2.2.5. The layer was added and published. However, the layer has got a yellow exclamation mark in the "Enabled?" field in Layers view. It is also missing from the Layer Preview page.

Everything seemed OK during the publishing process. I could also add the table to QGIS and it's shown well. Anything I was doing wrong?

Can anyone give me some hints about it? Thanks!

Alex

Comment: look in the log file?

Comment: There is no warning or error in the log file.

Comment: I was having a similar problem - I found checking the "Enabled" checkbox for the data source I was referencing fixed it.